# Отловить перерисовку Direct Show

Tags: c++, directshow

Вывел web camera на экран, через put_Owner((OAHWND)HWND), как можно отловить, когда винда начнет перерисовку кадра? 
Мой код 
1 Проиницилизировал графы контролы и тд

```
HRESULT hr(0);
 hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IFilterGraph2, (void**)&graph);
    if (hr < 0)
        return -1;
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CaptureGraphBuilder2, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ICaptureGraphBuilder2, (void**)&capture);
    if (hr < 0)
        return -1;
    hr = graph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (void**)&control);
    if (hr < 0)
        return -1;

    hr = graph->QueryInterface(IID_IVideoWindow, (void **)&pVidWin);
    if (hr < 0)
        return -1;
```

Дальше прилепил фильтр

```
HRESULT hr(0);
    VARIANT name;
    LONGLONG start = MAXLONGLONG, stop = MAXLONGLONG;
    unsigned long dev_count(0);
    ICreateDevEnum*     dev_enum(nullptr);
    IEnumMoniker*       enum_moniker(nullptr);
    IMoniker*           moniker(nullptr);
    IPropertyBag*       pbag(nullptr);
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SystemDeviceEnum, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ICreateDevEnum, (void**)&dev_enum);
    if (hr < 0)
        return -1;
    if (hr < 0)
        return -1;
    hr = dev_enum->CreateClassEnumerator(CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory, &enum_moniker, NULL);
    if (hr < 0)
        return -1;

    num_devices = 0;
    if (enum_moniker != nullptr)
        enum_moniker->Next(MAX_DEVICES, &moniker, &dev_count);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < dev_count; i++)
    {
        hr = moniker[i].BindToStorage(0, 0, IID_IPropertyBag, (void**)&pbag);
        if (hr >= 0)
        {
            VariantInit(&name);
            hr = pbag->Read(L"Description", &name, 0);
            if (hr < 0) hr = pbag->Read(L"FriendlyName", &name, 0);
            if (hr >= 0)
            {
                VideoDevice* dev = devices + num_devices++;
                BSTR ptr = name.bstrVal;

                for (int c = 0; *ptr; c++, ptr++)
                {
                    dev->filtername[c] = *ptr;
                    dev->friendlyname[c] = *ptr & 0xFF;
                }
                hr = graph->AddSourceFilterForMoniker(moniker + i, 0, dev->filtername, &dev->filter);
                if (hr != S_OK) num_devices--;
            }
            VariantClear(&name);
            hr = pbag->Release();
            if (hr < 0)
                return -1;
        }
        hr = moniker[i].Release();
        if (hr < 0)
            return -1;
    }

    return 0;
```

И сам рендеринг

```
HRESULT hr(0);
    LONGLONG start = MAXLONGLONG, stop = MAXLONGLONG;
    bool was_playing = playing;

    if (!dev->filter)
        return -1;

    if (playing)
        Stop();

    if (current)
    {
        hr = graph->RemoveFilter(current->filter);
        hr = graph->RemoveFilter(samplegrabberfilter);
        hr = graph->RemoveFilter(compressor);

        hr = graph->AddFilter(samplegrabberfilter, L"Sample Grabber");
        hr = graph->AddFilter(current->filter, current->filtername);
        hr = graph->AddFilter(compressor, L"compressor");
    }

    start = 0;
    current = dev;

#ifdef SHOW_DEBUG_RENDERER

    hr = capture->RenderStream(&PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE, &MEDIATYPE_Video, current->filter, compressor, 0);
    if (hr < 0)
        return -1;

    if (hr != S_OK)
    {
        SetSampleGrabber();
        hr = capture->RenderStream(&PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE, &MEDIATYPE_Video, current->filter, 0, samplegrabberfilter);
    }

    hr = pVidWin->put_Owner((OAHWND)hWndWin_);
    hr = pVidWin->put_WindowStyle(WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS);
    hr = pVidWin->put_Left(RplaceVideo.left);
    hr = pVidWin->put_Top(RplaceVideo.top);
    hr = pVidWin->put_Width(RplaceVideo.right - RplaceVideo.left);
    hr = pVidWin->put_Height(RplaceVideo.bottom - RplaceVideo.top);

#else
    hr = capture->RenderStream(&PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE, &MEDIATYPE_Video, current->filter, samplegrabberfilter, nullrenderer);
#endif
    hr = capture->ControlStream(&PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE, &MEDIATYPE_Video, current->filter, &start, &stop, 1, 2);
    if (hr < 0)
        return -1;

    if (was_playing)
        Start();


    return 0;

hr = control->Run();
```

Началась трансляция картинки с web camera на экран диалогового окна

Comment: Если на wiapi то вероятно `WM_PAINT` ?

Comment: @NewView К, сожаленью WM_PAINT вызовется только в начале, на первом кадре, дальше нет, мне надо синхронно вместе с direct show обновлять другие компоненты, но тогда я должен знать, когда direct обновляет кадр

Comment: Любопытства ради, покажите код, как это у вас устроено.. Там еще полно эвентов, посмотрите программой `spy` что там происходит с эвентами в вашем конкретном окошке, и ловите их в дальнейшем. Если кода много, киньте на какой либо гит или что-то в этом духе. Про шпиона: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-start-spy-increment?view=vs-2019

Comment: @NewView Я изменил свой вопрос, добавив код, самое главное по direct, евенты пытался словить классом IMediaEventEx, но без успеха

Comment: мде.. начните со скилета в коде, что откуда и в какой момент зовется, интересует по отношению к WM_ эвентам, последовательность.

Comment: @NewView Сообщения анализировать бессмысленно, так как DirectShow их не использует для рендеринга графики (максимум, для уведомления о завершении воспроизведения). Поскольку DirectShow использует для рендеринга DirectX, перерисовка изображения осуществляется очень часто, и количество порождаемых сообщений было бы слишком большим. Обновлять что-то синхронно с DirectX выглядит довольно плохой идеей, чисто по причинам производительности. Скорее всего, ответ - "Писать свой фильтр-рендерер".

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Спасибо!!

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight может, Вы знаете как расположить на directshow gdi объект? я рисую его bitmap и в onDraw() отрисовываю, но когда транслируется видео, gdi моргает на видео, так как обновляю я его  c помощью Invalidate(), а если не обновлять, то gdi уйдет на задний план под видео, буду благодраен за любую помощь

Comment: "*как расположить на directshow gdi объект*" - это все равно что "как догнать феррари на хромой кобыле", никак. GDI - устаревший интерфейс, который просто не рассчитан на вывод графики с такой же скоростью, как DirectShow.

Comment: Если вам нужно интегрировать в граф DirectShow свое изображение, как вариант, использовать SampleGrabber (его документация не указывает возможность модификации захватываемого изображения, но на самом деле она есть, например, это используется здесь: https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Paint-With-Light ). Либо, как я уже сказал, создавать свои фильтры специально под эту задачу.

Comment: Чтоб не моргало в GDI надо из WM_ERASEBKGND возвращать нечто отличное 0, при отрисовке данного квадрата, подсказка - надо проверять Rectangle

Comment: @NewView , можете поподробнее, пожалуйста, всю голову сломал, я вызываю прорисовку gdi из OnDraw(), его же вызывает Invalidate(FALSE); Rectangle это же прямоугольник чего его проверять то?

Comment: Так создайте метку `WM_ERASEBKGND` там же где `WM_PAINT` и попробуйте вернуть от туда 1 например, дальше сами все увидите..

Comment: Вопрос задан неудачно, в т.ч. с учётом добавления кода. Нужно начать с того зачем нужно вообще "отлавливать" с тем, чтобы кроме того, что это невозможно, не нужно, и неправильно, вам также предложили бы и решение. Вы не можете одними устаревшими средствами (GDI) рисовать поверх других и несовместимых устаревших средств (вывод видео с DirectShow) по фундаментальным причинам.